# Encrypt file to gpg from website (via PHP)

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg

In localhost I am able to use PHP to generate .txt files from database records and encrypt them to .gpg using PHP exec and GPG4win. However, when I upload my php scripts to my webserver, this don't work anymore because the GPG4win program is on my local machine. How can I go about encrypting the files i create from my website? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to install the `gpg` executable on your webserver.  Or you can use the PECL gpg extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php

Comment: Thank you. I will attempt this and let you know. Cheers mate.

Comment: Do you have SSH access and can install software on your server?

Comment: @DanielRuf, I'm running Centos on a VPS server so I believe I do.